# Compile Error C3861 Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, dll, compiler-errors

I'm getting two errors and can't figure it out for the life of me...
I've researched it on google for the last few hours. I'm getting now where.
Here are the compile errors I'm getting.

```
    2   IntelliSense: identifier "RegisterShader" is undefined  c:\users\administrator\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\dllmain.cpp   18  20  

Error   1   error C3861: 'RegisterShader': identifier not found c:\users\administrator\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\dllmain.cpp   50  1
```

// stdafx.h

```
// stdafx.h : include file for standard system include files,
// or project specific include files that are used frequently, but
// are changed infrequently
//
#pragma once
#include "targetver.h"

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN             // Exclude rarely-used stuff from Windows headers
// Windows Header Files:
#include <windows.h>

// TODO: reference additional headers your program requires here
#include <detours.h>
#include "typedefs.h"
```

// stdafx.cpp

```
// stdafx.cpp : source file that includes just the standard includes
// blopsII.pch will be the pre-compiled header
// stdafx.obj will contain the pre-compiled type information

#include "stdafx.h"

// TODO: reference any additional headers you need in STDAFX.H
// and not in this file
```

// typedefs.h

```
#ifndef TYPEDEFS_H
#define TYPEDEFS_H

#define OFF_REGISTERSHADER 0x00715690

typedef float  vec_t;
typedef vec_t  vec2_t[2];
typedef vec_t  vec3_t[3];
typedef vec_t  vec4_t[4];
typedef int    qhandle_t;

typedef int ( * tRegisterShader )( char* szName, int unk );

#endif
```

// typedefs.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"

tRegisterShader RegisterShader = ( tRegisterShader )OFF_REGISTERSHADER;
```

// dllmain.cpp

```
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "stdafx.h"

//#include "typedefs.h"

DWORD dwHook = 0x6ADC30;

void callback()
{

    qhandle_t white = RegisterShader("white", 3);
}


int __cdecl hkRender()
{
    _asm pushad;
    callback();
    _asm popad;
}


BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:



    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Several ways to do this:

**dllmain.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "typedefs.h"

extern tRegisterShader RegisterShader;
```

The rest is as you already have it.

---

Alternatively, you can "publish" the variable defined in typedefs.cpp by putting the extern at the bottom of typedefs.h:

**typedefs.h**

```
#ifndef TYPEDEFS_H
#define TYPEDEFS_H

#define OFF_REGISTERSHADER 0x00715690

typedef float  vec_t;
typedef vec_t  vec2_t[2];
typedef vec_t  vec3_t[3];
typedef vec_t  vec4_t[4];
typedef int    qhandle_t;

typedef int ( * tRegisterShader )( char* szName, int unk );

extern tRegisterShader RegisterShader;

#endif
```

The latter method is common when publishing a global variable of a type defined in a header file where the variable is defined in the matching .cpp file. Declaring it as extern in the header effectively exposes it to anyone including the header (including your dllmain.cpp).

Comment: My include file for typedefs.h is inside stdafx.h? should I put the extern only in my dllmain.cpp?

Comment: @Pepsi_1 actually, i'd put the extern at the bottom of you typedefs.h header file just inside the #endif ending your guard post. I was about to update the answer here to suggest that is another alternative.